# Scaling Spring Batch remote partitioning with kafka

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-kafka

I need to scale spring batch job by remote partitioning with kafka.

I want to run manager step on one VM and worker steps on different VMs. For that I have some questions -

1. If my manager VM instance goes down in between before the completion of all worker steps. So it possible for another VM to become manager and complete the manager step?
2. I have noticed that when I have 3 worker step VMs running with kafka based remote partitioning then first or one of the worker is picked more partitions compare to other worker VMs. Can it possible to equally distribute the equal no of partitions between all these workers ?

Answer (score 0):

> If my manager VM instance goes down in between before the completion of all worker steps. So it possible for another VM to become manager and complete the manager step?

No, there is no manager (re)election in Spring Batch. If the manager VM fails, you need to restart the job instance.

> I have noticed that when I have 3 worker step VMs running with kafka based remote partitioning then first or one of the worker is picked more partitions compare to other worker VMs. Can it possible to equally distribute the equal no of partitions between all these workers ?

This depends on how you distribute work and how you configure workers. If you put step execution requests in the same queue, then all workers will pick up requests from the same queue. Therefore, if one worker is faster than others, it will do more work. If you want to equally distribute work among workers, then you need to setup a queue for each worker and distribute step execution requests in round-robin fashion to equally assign partitions.

Comment: thanks @Mahmound Ben Hassine. So in that case if steps are still working or not failed Spring batch mark that job is failed ? Or how to identify that only manager is failed.

Comment: When workers finish their work, they update their status in the db and shutdown. When you restart the job instance, the manager will reconcile the status of the partitioned step and resume execution.

Comment: Ok thanks @Mahmound Ben Hassine Then may be I will try find some solution to auto restart job on another node if manager goes down on one node.